# When are reciprocal pronouns preceded by "to"?

Tags: pronouns

I Have Been reading respect reciprocal pronouns and their rules/uses, but I haven't Found the reason why sometimes they are preceded by "to" .For example:

"Brenda and Lana speak TO each other every day"
"Peter and David hate each other"

Both are valids? Or Am i losing a grammar fact respect to this? 
Can I say "Brenda and Lana speak each other every day" / "Peter and David hate TO each other?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Brenda and Lana speak English every day.  The object of "speak" is some attribute of the speech.  The object of "hate" is the target of that hate.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the verb, not the nouns. In your sentences, *speak* is intransitive and *hate* is transitive. That's why the word *hate* can take *each other* as a direct object whereas *speak* can't.

> An intransitive verb has two characteristics. First, it is an action verb, expressing a doable activity like arrive, go, lie, sneeze, sit, die, etc. Second, unlike a transitive verb, it will not have a direct object receiving the action.
>   [- Grammar Bites!](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/intransitiveverb.htm)